# Insert long string into Access DB using parametrised query in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I'm trying to update a classic ASP application and as part of the update I've tried to replace dynamic SQL using string concatenation with a parametrised query.

The problem is that the parameters won't accept a value which is longer than 210 characters.

I get the following error...

> ADODB.Parameter error '800a0d5d'
>
> Application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation.
>
> /admin/Save_product_subcategories.asp, line 30

My first attempt looks like this...

```
SQLString = "UPDATE Product_SubCategories 
    SET SubCategory=?, Description=? 
    WHERE SubCategoryID=?"

Set courseCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command") 
courseCommand.ActiveConnection = objConn
courseCommand.CommandText = SQLString

courseCommand.Parameters(0).value = cleanCategory 
courseCommand.Parameters(1).Value = cleanDescription
courseCommand.Parameters(2).value = cleanSubCategoryId
```

I've tried manually setting the parameter type and increasing the size of the parameter...

```
courseCommand.Parameters(1).Type = 203
courseCommand.Parameters(1).Size = 300
courseCommand.Parameters(1).Type = adLongVarWChar
```

I've also tried creating a parameter with the command.CreateParameter method but that gives the same error.

```
param = courseCommand.CreateParameter(,,,,cleanDescription)
'or
param = courseCommand.CreateParameter(,adLongVarWChar,,,cleanDescription)
'or
param = courseCommand.CreateParameter(,adLongVarWChar,,300,cleanDescription)
courseCommand.Parameters(1) = param
```

I'm beginning to think that my only option is to go back to dynamic sql.

Edit:

I tried to Append the parameter instead of adding it to the collection using the array index but none of the parameters worked after that.

> Provider error '80020005'
>
> Type mismatch.
>
> /admin/Save_product_subcategories.asp, line 31

Comment: Which line is 'line 30' and which is 'line 31'?

Comment: In the first code block it was where I assigned the cleanDescrption parameter to the Parameters array value `courseCommand.Parameters(1).Value = cleanDescription`. Then when I used the CreateParameter method it was where I assigned the parameter to the Parameters array `courseCommand.Parameters(1) = param`

Comment: I asked the same question on another forum that seems to have a more active ASP community and it's been answered http://forums.aspfree.com/asp-development-5/insert-long-string-into-access-database-using-parametrised-query-classic-asp-538500.html. I was just going to wait and see if he want's to answer here for the rep but my latest replies to the thread seem to be getting lost in moderation.

Comment: What DB and driver are you using?

Comment: A Microsoft Access mdb file and the 32bit version of this driver http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for this the answer is to use a Recordset.

```
SQLString = "select  * from Product_SubCategories where 1=0"

Set rs= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") 
rs.open  SQLString , objConn, 1,3 'open as keyset ,lock optimistic that will create empty recordset for you
' Add new record
rs.AddNew
'assign values
rs("SubCategoryID")=cleanSubCategoryId
rs("Description")=cleanDescription
rs("SubCategory")=cleanCategory
' send new record with values to database
rs.Update
'close recordset
rs.close
'destroy recordset object
se rs=nothing
```